# ValidationMessageFor not showing an error message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've read a few similar questions and answers here on SO but neither solution solves my problem.

The issue is that validation works in terms of preventing from saving values to db but error messages don't show up. I think I followed all steps how to achieve that but it doesn't help:

**Model:**

```
    public class DocumentsModel
    {
       [Required(ErrorMessage = "Choose decision")]
       public string Decision { get; set; }
    
       [Required(ErrorMessage = "Choose date")]
       public DateTime? Manual_date { get; set; }      
    }
```

**View:**

```
    <td>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Manual_date, new { @type = "date", @hidden = "hidden", @Name = "Manual_date", @class = "form-control datepicker" })
    
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.Manual_date)
    </td>
    
    <td>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.Decision, new List<SelectListItem>
             {new SelectListItem { Text="None", Value= "None", Selected=true},
              new SelectListItem { Text="xyz", Value="xyz"}
             }, new { Name = "Decision", @hidden = "hidden" })
    
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.Decision)
    </td>
```

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Update(DocumentsModel doc)
            {
             RRRdb db = new RRRdb();
    
             if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                 //saving...
                }
             return RedirectToAction("XYZ");
             }
```

**Scripts:**

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

**Web.config:**

```
      <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
      </appSettings>
```

Of course I make dropdownlist and textbox visible when needed using jQuery so user can use those fields. As I said in the beginning - validation itself works (not save values from fields unless they are filled) but messages won't show up next to fields. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your elements inside a `form` tag in *view*

```
@model Test.Models.DocumentsModel
<form action="update" method="post">

<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.Manual_date, new { @type = "date", @hidden = "hidden", @Name = "Manual_date", @class = "form-control datepicker" })

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => modelItem.Manual_date)
</div>

<div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => modelItem.Decision, new List<SelectListItem>
             {new SelectListItem { Text="None", Value= "None"},
              new SelectListItem { Text="xyz", Value="xyz"}
             }, "select..", new { Name = "Decision" })

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => modelItem.Decision)
</div>
<div>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</div>

</form>
```

and in your action, to display **validation messages** return your model if `ModelState.IsValid` is not true;

```
// Get
    public ActionResult Update()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "edit";

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Update(DocumentsModel doc)
    {
        RRRdb db = new RRRdb();

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(doc);
        }
        //saving...
        return RedirectToAction("XYZ");
    }
```

Comment: I followed you example but still have no message shown up

Comment: What I noticed now is that ```@Html.ValidationSummary();``` works and returns error message. Unfortunately, ValidationMessageFor doesn't work, do you know what could be a reason?

Comment: Look at this link: https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/8830648/-html-validationmessagefor-did-not-work-as-expected I think for my Html Helpers it's not possible to use it

Comment: I tested and it's work. Please, make sure you don't forget anything

Comment: I tried many ways but nothing helps. I use ```@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Home", FormMethod.Post))``` and rest of the code is as yours (I created a table where I use dropdownlists in each row)